# Add id VerticalLayout SapUi5

Tags: sapui5

I'm trying to add id to each div of vertical layout. I can do it with javascript but I would like do it without.

code for generate the vertial layout:

```
    var oText1 = new sap.ui.commons.TextField({value:"Edward"});
    var oText2 = new sap.ui.commons.TextField({value:"Maria"});

    var oLayoutVer = new sap.ui.layout.VerticalLayout("LayoutVer", {
        content: [oText1, oText2]
    });
```

This gen:

```
   <div id="LayoutVer" data-sap-ui="LayoutVer" class="sapUiVlt sapuiVlt">
       <div class="sapUiVltCell sapuiVltCell"><input id="__field1" ... value="Edward"></div>
       <div class="sapUiVltCell sapuiVltCell"><input id="__field2" ... value="Maria"></div>
  </div>
```

I find it: http://scn.sap.com/thread/3386749, but i would like to it without onAfterRendering, thank you

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are trying to style those elements or query for it from JavaScript. You can make use of the nth-child selector like this without the need for any additional id:

CSS

```
#LayoutVer:nth-child(2) {
  width: 100%;
}
```

jQuery

```
var secondChild = $(#LayoutVer:nth-child(2));
var allChildren = $(#LayoutVer).children();
```

Generally speaking there is rarely a need for the use of ids from a css perspective. Since you use css selectors to query elements and have various other possibilities to traverse the DOM with jQuery you rarely need ids here, too. The only real use is to get the UI5 Controls via `sap.ui.getCore().byId()`. The divs you are trying to access are no UI5 Controls though - they are just elements from the vertical layouts html output.

The point is: I can't see any reason to have ids on those divs :)

BR
Chris

Answer (score 0):

I think you can give the sId for each element you are adding to vertical layout created and UI5 internally creates a div for each element added. You can control those elements using the given sId will be a better option rather than trying to assign id for each parent div created by UI5.

$("#element sId").parent() will also helpful in controlling the div you asked

Answer (score 0):

What you need is to pass the ID in the constructor and create an loop...

```
for ( var int = 1; int < 10; int++) {
    var id = "layout" + int; // creates "layout1" .. "layout2"
    var oText1 = new sap.ui.commons.TextField({value:"Edward"});
    var oText2 = new sap.ui.commons.TextField({value:"Maria"});

    var oLayoutVer = new sap.ui.layout.VerticalLayout(id, {
        content: [oText1, oText2]
    });
}
```

now you can access via ID ;-)